# Stata: Custom format for stats() in esttab

Tags: stata

How can I surround all the numbers in the 'N' row in the output below with curly braces? Is there a custom format I can define to do this? Rather than outputting '74', I need to output '{74}'.

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear
eststo: regress price weight mpg

test (_cons=0) (_b[weight]=1)

esttab, stats(N, fmt(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

`esttab, stats(N, layout({@}) label(N))`

Comment: Perfect. Works great.